# 2 Internet Explorer (32 bit) processes taking up CPU

Tags: windows-8.1, 64-bit, internet-explorer, process-explorer

I am running Windows 8.1 N Pro x64 and there are 2 Internet Explorer processes that must be for 32 bit. It stays there even if Internet Explorer is closed. I tried ending the processes but they just come back. I run a x64 Internet Explorer. How can I stop those processes?

Comment: After a full reboot (not hybrid shutdown), do the IE processes restart? If so, check Sysinternals' Autoruns to see how they start. Also, check for malware that might be starting them.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik it's just when I start IE. But it only does that when connected.

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20110511175028/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/askie/archive/2009/03/20/how-to-i-determine-which-ie-tabs-go-to-which-iexplore-exe-process-when-using-internet-explorer-8.aspx

Answer (score 1):

With your more complete description of the "issue", it's easy to answer: that's normal operation of IE: one instance for the frame window, and additional instances for each tab.

See [How to determine which IE tabs goes to which IEXPLORE.EXE process...](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/askie/archive/2009/03/20/how-to-i-determine-which-ie-tabs-go-to-which-iexplore-exe-process-when-using-internet-explorer-8.aspx) for a more complete description, but basically, when you look at the Command Line used to start each instance, you'll see:

**"C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE"**: frame window

**"C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE" SCODEF:*m* CREDAT:*x* /prefetch:2** : tab 1

**"C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE" SCODEF:*n* CREDAT:*y* /prefetch:2** : tab 2

where *m* & *n* is the process id (PID) of the parent process and *x* and *y* are random integers.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/askie/archive/2009/03/20/how-to-i-determine-which-ie-tabs-go-to-which-iexplore-exe-process-when-using-internet-explorer-8.aspx not found